# Eclipse RCP: How to pre-select a new project wizard?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have an Eclipse plugin using RCP and Eclipse 4.5.2. This plugin is for developing a project of type "X". Right now, under File > New > Project... I have "X" within a category of "MyPlugin". I'd have to expand "MyPlugin" then double click on "X" to open the X version of the new project wizard.

**Is it possible to pre-select "X" when clicking on File > New > Project...?**

This would mean the category "MyPlugin" would have to be automatically expanded to show the pre-selected "X". Here's a snippet of my plugin.xml where the new project wizard for X is defined:

```xml
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.newWizards">
    <wizard 
        category="com.mycompany.myproduct.core.ui.newWizards" 
        class="com.mycompany.myproduct.newXProjectWizard" 
        finalPerspective="com.mycompany.myproduct.ui.XPerspective" 
        hasPages="true" 
        icon="icons/project_new.gif" 
        id="com.mycompany.myproduct.newXProjectWizard" 
        name="%Names.NewProject" 
        preferredPerspectives="com.mycompany.myproduct.XPerspective" 
        project="true">
        <description>
            Create a new X project
        </description>
    </wizard>
</extension>
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this. You can add your wizard to the list shown at the top level of the 'File > New' menu using a perspective shortcut.

Comment: Thanks, actually a shortcut is even better for my purposes! I applied [your other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29510268/1371217) and it worked. Caveat to others: you need to reset the perspective for the change to take effect!